# Redirection 301 of 1 domain to another site with utms

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i have a problem trying to redirect 1 domain to another with `utms`, i need to do it for tracking email campaigns.

For example the initial domain is `mydomain.es`

the target urls is `https://www.exampledomain.com/titulaciones/master-psicopedagogia-online?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=PAID-SEARCH_OPENUAX_MPPG_MU-PSICOPEDAGOG%C3%8DA_POSTGRADO_SALUD-Y-DEPORTE_NA_ES_GLOBAL_GOO_GENER_NA_PROS_NA_NA_NA&utm_term=GLOBAL`

I tried in the htaccess with:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.exampledomain.com/titulaciones/master-psicopedagogia-online?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=PAID-SEARCH_OPENUAX_MPPG_MU-PSICOPEDAGOG%C3%8DA_POSTGRADO_SALUD-Y-DEPORTE_NA_ES_GLOBAL_GOO_GENER_NA_PROS_NA_NA_NA&utm_term=GLOBAL
```

, the redirection is done but don't keep the `utm`s that i need to track the campaigns.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: @anubhava this is the final url that i get after the redirect  https://www.exampledomain.com/titulaciones/master-psicopedagogia-online without the utms that i need for tracking.

Comment: It is stripping your query string. May be you have old browser cache or some other rule conflicting with this one

Comment: i dont have any rule, because i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Just rename this .htaccess to `.htac` and retest in new browser to see what happens

Comment: Solved, thank you!